# How to ask team lead to let me know if he breaks or changes something

Tags: management, communication, united-kingdom, software-development

We are a small team which is about to launch a redesigned website undergoing a major facelift.  Due to the nature of the timeframe I have less workload and my Manager wants me to test things to make sure everything is ok. We have a full-time tester as well. While testing I found that there are some issues which weren't there first.  They were either a result of negligence from my manager or other developer, but it falls onto me as it is related to the front end.  For example, I was checking the website on mobile and the menu doesn't load but on the desktop it does  This means they have done their work on making the menu dynamic, but not the other bit and didn't tell me.

Over time my team has polluted my work with *everything they can throw and see what sticks* because they think they know my job well.

If I don't do something assigned to me or take a bit of time, my manager is quick to raise issue or have other devs sit with me to complete task.

With a problem as big as menu not loading on mobile, the I.T Director is assuming that the guy hired to a front end (me) isn't good at his job. In reality, it is the person who worked on the menu didn't work on mobile. If the change is something on backend, the manager is quickly agitated towards me, asking *why*, and his memory isn't too good towards me.

My question is, as a subordinate, how much right do I have to tell my manager that my design was fine, but after he or other dev worked on it, it has been ruined, and that theright person should fix it?

*The other dev was quick to remove the SVN history so one cannot know who did what couple of months ago, so it is war of words*

Comment: If anyone over here attempted to remove some of the version history, he would be out the door the same day!

Comment: Try to get out of the mindset of labelling bugs as caused by 'negligence'.  They're bugs - people make mistakes.  Once you start getting into the blame game, it starts affecting your working relationships with your co-workers.

Comment: First thing to do is make sure no one but an admin can touch SVN history. I second the suggestion that he should get the boot for that.

Comment: I love the comments here, the colleague is a prick. He replaced all files with new files, then blamed on me and when manager said to get it back i.e rollback/restore he did something where no one can see history earlier then that time. the manager won't know that magic and only he does, thus firing him is not an option coz he creates mess and manager loves it coz 5% of work,  95% of mess is better than nothing. @SnarkShark I don't mean bug as negligence. I meant ignoring the fact that part need work too and not doing it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yes, but they screw things which aren't related to them, and If I do same, the manager is all blazing runs on me.

Comment: "how much right do I have to tell my manager that my design was fine, but after he or other dev worked on it, it has been ruined, and that the right person should fix it?" - None.  If somebody I managed said this to me, I would make sure, I no longer managed them.

Comment: The major problem here seems to be version control. You can't effectively test software that is changing on the fly.

Answer (score 12):

You're tasked with testing, and during your tests you find bugs?... that's what testing is for. You report the bugs and then they can be resolved. Playing the point the finger game isn't very constructive. If you are documenting properly this shouldn't worry you.

I troubleshoot for a living (not software). The professional way to handle it is to make a report on what doesn't work correctly, possible lines of inquiry into how to resolve the problems and focus on solutions rather than blame.

People shouldn't be messing with the version controls but that doesn't seem to be your role. That is an issue in itself and I would make a report on it as follows without doing the blame game.

'While investigating the cause of X problem I found that previous versions are unavailable which makes it difficult to pinpoint cause. This may indicate a problem with the version control system or deliberate tampering. Moving forwards I have identified XX and XY as primary reasons for the failure of YY when WW situation occurs. etc,.... (then work towards resolution strategies).'

Comment: Well manager showed me attitude when I indented the code while performing a test task which was UX enhancement as he wasn't able to figure out what I added/remove because of his lack of knowledge and I didn't tell him because if a person is rude to me after offering numerous time help, one has to stop. If I do testing fixes and he will have the same behaviour with me, not indenting/indenting code. I will have to report his manager for his misbehaviour.

Comment: How to deal with a manager in these situations would be a very different question than the one posed. But reporting your manager to someone higher up for hurting your feelings is generally a bad idea unless you have some leverage/connection with the higher up. In this case it's both your manager and your team lead you want to complain about. Such a complaint might backfire very badly. There are other strategies you could use.

Comment: Do u want to edit the question and provide a better answer?

Comment: Not really, I don't know your whole situation, if you pose the question you want answered, we can all try and help you. Editing the existing question would invalidate all the current answers but you could delete it and start again.

Comment: @Nofel "Manager showed me attitude when I intended the code" - For style changes that don't change functionality consider making these a separate change, e.g. on a Friday afternoon. And mark them as such "fixed indents, etc."

Answer (score -2):

As software is deterministic and there are sufficient tools to track any changes this should be really easy to solve.

No using such a system (in a tamper-free way) puts burden-of-proof for failure pretty much on the company.

Having bug´s that make it to production also points to some other problems in the processes. (Testing and deployment)

Start improving your teams process to get out of such situations in the future and into a constructive work environment.

Comment: I just assumed it because "the problem as big as menu not loading" would not be a big problem if just discovered in a testing environment. That´s  what testing is for, isn´t it?

Comment: Sorry, I answer questions here in the spirit of what I comprehend from the poster text, trying it to be useful. If you know any more or have a different take on it feel free to post an answer yourself. If you find my post is bad advice feel free to downvote.